# Problem with the CakePHP Search Plugin

Tags: cakephp

I've trying to use the [CakePHP Search Plugin](http://cakedc.com/eng/downloads/view/cakephp_search_plugin) along with the [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog) available in the Cookbook and even though I followed the instruction to the letter I Keep getting this error message :**Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'parseCriteria' at line 1** .

This is what I've done:

**Model:**

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $displayField = 'title';

    public $filterArgs = array(
            array('name' => 'title','type' => 'string'),
    );
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

   var $name = 'Posts';
   public $components = array('Search.Prg');

   public $presetVars = array(
    array('field' => 'title', 'type' => 'value'),
   );

   function beforeFilter() {
       parent::beforeFilter();      
   }

   public function index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate = array(
      'conditions' => $this->Post->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs));
    $this->paginate = array('limit' => 15);
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
   }

}
```

**View:**

```
<?php
   echo $this->Form->create('Post', array(
       'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'index'), $this->params['pass'])
            ));
   echo $this->Form->input('title', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true));        
   echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
   echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting that error because you haven't attached the behavior to your Post model.  At the top of your Post model add:

```
var $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');
```